# how to run a node.js github repository as a service in another repository on github actions

Tags: node.js, github, integration-testing, github-actions, end-to-end

So I have a project that needs a "fake" API to do some functional testing on user scenarios; so my idea was creating a simple little node.js project and getting to return some dummy json data depending on a few endpoints to test several use cases of my application.

I have a separate repository containing this fake API and I'm wondering how I should go about adding it into my github actions workflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `actions/checkout@v2` to pull another repo into your worker.

See the example below:

```
name: PullExternalRepo

on: workflow_dispatch

jobs:
  PullRepo:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
      - name: Install Node
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2-beta
        with:
          node-version: '12'
      - name: Install external repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          repository: your_org/repo_name
          path: './place/to/clone/repo/into'
      - name: Install deps and run
        run: |
          cd ./place/to/clone/repo/into
          npm install
          npm start
```

Added note about pulling specific branches:

If you are trying to pull a non-default branch, you need to add the `ref` property to the checkout action, as seen in the example below.

```
...
      - name: Install external repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          repository: your_org/repo_name
          path: './place/to/clone/repo/into'
          ref: 'some-other-branch'
...
```

Comment: as a complete beginner does the @v2 refer to the release tag on the master branch?

Comment: It refers to the release tag of the action repo, not the repo you are attempting to pull. I.e. https://github.com/actions/checkout/tree/v2.

If you want to pull a specific tag of your repository, you can do that by adding the 'ref' tag into the 'with' section, like: ref: my-branch